# How to track user on google map in real-time?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tracking

I am developing one application, in which I want to achieve the following things using Google Map :

1. Person A can get tracked by multiple user.
2. Each and every person who are tracking Person A can put a Pin in Map and make a radius so that they can Track Person A on different location.
3. If Person B is tracking Person A in Santa Clara location and radius is 30meters then whenever Person A enters or leaves that location then Person B will get a notification.
4. If Person A has arrived in tracked location, and travelling then **we have to display speed, directions in which he is travelling on Map in real-time.**
5. So there can be multiple locations in which Person A gets tracked. and we have to display real-time direction in which he is travelling and current speed. **Like UBER app**.

I had a call with google support and she told me **"You have to implement your own tracking mechanism by maintaining geocode records in database"**. But If I implement like this then each and every second I have to send geolocation to the server and retrieve it.

Is there any other solution for this problem ?

Thanks,
Abbas Mulani

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own mechanism by saving the markers that person B adds and then checking them against the location of person A for each record. You will also need to save the location of person A along with his speed and location and then display it on the map.